# Is it possible to create series of stacked bar charts using dimplejs?

Tags: dimple.js

Is it possible to create a chart with two stacked chart series side by side using dimple?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it's here in the examples:

http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical_grouped_stacked